# How to find the first & Last element in a Dataframe Column & Trim the value between those elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been working with coordinate Data. (Lat & Long)

**Background**

```
Act Df = 

Index       Latitude            Longitude
0           66.36031097267725   23.714807357485936
1           66.36030099322495   23.71479548193769
2
.
.
```

```
Flt Df =

Index       Latitude            Longitude
0           66.34622070356742   23.687960586306179
1           66.34620931053996   23.687951092116624
2
.
.
```

```
len(Actual) = 12053 
len(Fleet) = 8000
```

The above data shows that, Fleet data coordinate points hold a shorter area in Actual Data Lat & Long Graph.

**Note:**

Fleet Lat & Long values may not be necessary equal to Actual Lat & long values, But it holds shorter area in Actual Lat/Long graph points

**Requirement**

I want to trim the part of Actual Lat/Long data based on values in Fleet Lat/Long Data.

My requirement is when i plotted in Open Street map or matplotlib both Actual Lat/Long data & Fleet Lat/Long Data must be follow same path.(Location may not be necessarily same)

**What i tried:**

I used Arithmetic operation like

```
actual_data[(actual_data['Latitude'] <= fleet_data_Lat_start_point) & (actual_data['Longitude'] <= fleet_data_Long_start_point) & (actual_data['Latitude'] <= fleet_data_Lat_end_point) & (actual_data['Longitude'] <= fleet_data_Long_end_point)]
```

Comment: difficult to understant without a sample, i try:for each point in actual df, you want the nearest point of fleet df?

Comment: Exactly !!!!@Frenchy

Comment: ok so the job will be long following the number of data....

Comment: Final Goal is : for each point in actual df, you want the nearest point of fleet df.
So before start doing that, i thought of scrubbing/trimming the data. So I posted  above question@Frenchy

Comment: Yes !!! @Frenchy

Comment: i have read your code, you keep first value < 100m in combined df, but no lucky, if this data is at the end of fleet, what do you do for other actual values, then you dont iterate when arrived at the end of fleet..

Comment: **code explanation :** 
- For 1st  `df_actual_data lat/lon`  point, the condition `if (distance > old_distance)  and (old_distance < max_distance)` will be carried for every `df_Fleet_data lat/lon`. 
- If one point of  `df_Fleet_data lat/lon` satisfied the condition, then previous value will be saved in `df_combined_data` and then the loop breaks. 
- After that, 2nd  `df_actual_data lat/lon` points will come in and starts matching with next `Fleet_data lat/lon` point. (wont consider previous matched  point )
- In that way I will iterate with every `df_actual_data lat/lon` points. @Frenchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my solution: ia m using the library geopy to calculate the distance.

You could choose to calulate the distance in geodesic() or great_circle(), either the function distance = geodesic.
and you could change the metric `.km` to `.miles` or to `m` or to `ft` if you prefer another metric

```
from geopy.distance import lonlat, distance, great_circle,geodesic

dmin=[]
for index, r in df_actual.iterrows():
    valmin = df_fleet.apply(lambda x:
                            distance(lonlat(x['Longitude'], x['Latitude']),
                                     lonlat(r['Longitude'], r['Latitude'])).km,axis=1).min()
    dmin.append(valmin)

df_actual['nearest to fleet(km)'] = dmin
print(df_actual)
```

if you want all fleet point < 100m of each actual points , you do

```
for ai, a in df_actual.iterrows():
    actual = lonlat(a['Longitude'], a['Latitude'])
    filter = df_fleet.apply(lambda x: 
              distance(lonlat(x['Longitude'], x['Latitude']), actual).meters < 100 ,axis=1)

    print(f"for {(a['Longitude'], a['Latitude'])}"); print(df_fleet[filter])
```

The last solution is based on Tree calcul and i think its very very very fast
i am using the scipy spatial which calculates the nearest point in spatial and give the result in euclidian distance. i have just adapted the lat,lon in x,y,z spatial points to have the right result (in geodesic or haversine). Here i generate 2 dataframes of (lat ,lon) 15000 and 10000 rows and i am searching the five nearest for each df1 in df2

```
from random import uniform
from math import radians, sin, cos
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def to_cartesian(lat, lon):
    lat = radians(lat); lon = radians(lon)
    R = 6371
    x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
    y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
    z = R * sin(lat)
    return x, y , z

def newpoint():
    return uniform(23, 24), uniform(66, 67)

def ckdnearest(gdA, gdB, bcol):   
    nA = np.array(list(zip(gdA.x, gdA.y, gdA.z)) )
    nB = np.array(list(zip(gdB.x, gdB.y, gdB.z)) )
    btree = cKDTree(nB)

    dist, idx = btree.query(nA,k=5) #search the first 5 (k=5) nearest point df2 for each point of df1
    dist = [d for d in dist]
    idx = [s for s in idx]

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'distance': dist, 
                                 'index of df2' : idx})

    return df

#create the first df (actual)
n = 15000
lon,lat = [],[]
for x,y in (newpoint() for x in range(n)):
    lon += [x];lat +=[y]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})
df1['x'], df1['y'], df1['z'] = zip(*map(to_cartesian, df1.lat, df1.lon))
#-----------------------

#create the second df (fleet)
n = 10000
lon,lat = [],[]
for x,y in (newpoint() for x in range(n)):
    lon += [x];lat +=[y]
id = [x for x in range(n)]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'lat': lat, 'lon': lon})
df2['x'], df2['y'], df2['z'] = zip(*map(to_cartesian, df2.lat, df2.lon))
#-----------------------

df = ckdnearest(df1, df2, 'unused')

print(df)
```

if you want just 1 nearest point without cartesian coord:

```
def ckdnearest(gdA, gdB, bcol):   
    nA = np.array(list(zip(gdA.lat, gdA.lon)))
    nB = np.array(list(zip(gdB.lat, gdB.lon)))
    btree = cKDTree(nB)
    dist, idx = btree.query(nA,k=1) #search the first  nearest point df2 
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'distance': dist, 'index of df2' : idx})
    return df
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!!!
But my computing time is very higher. My `Fleet_data has the shape of 11734*3 and Actual Data has the shape of 12500*3` . **So the computation time is very higher**.  
__Is there is any method/solution so that i can match with less computation time, (for example : matching the points one after the another)__.@Frechy

Comment: i think the only method to have less computation is to use dask or multithread, but  need a strong analyse -> split the dataframe and so on, but all the settings time counts time...how much your elapse time? with 100%cpu?

Comment: After we could iterate the fleet df and if you find a distance <  300 meters, you stop and go next actual. you havent necessary the nearest but one of them

Comment: As per your 2nd comment above, how can i iterate with every fleet_data and find its distance with actual_data and use a condition if the distance is < 100 meters then find the minimum of all values which are less than 100. I tried in your above program `valmin = df_fleet.apply(lambda x:
                            distance(lonlat(x['Longitude'], x['Latitude']),
                                     lonlat(r['Longitude'], r['Latitude'])).m < 100, axis=1).min()`
But I cant able to produce result.
**Could you suggest a correct way ?** @Frenchy

Comment: see my add about that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189774/discussion-between-ponraj-rajesh-and-frenchy).

Comment: i have found someting very fast, i'll explain in few days i am busy for now

Comment: let's go with the new solution. i am testing 2 df with respextively 15000 an 10000 rows .  i have the 5 nearest in less of 5ms!!  the result df gives, for each index of df1 (actual for you) the five nearest  distances and the five index of df2 (fleet for you) corresponding.  you just adapt the value of k in the loop if you want another number of nearest.

Comment: Thank you for the solution I will test my Data and share my results...
Also, Is there is any reason for converting the Lat'/Long points to cartesian coordinates ? @Frenchy

Comment: Also, I need only 1 nearest neighbor value so that I can choose K=1 right ???  @Frenchy

Comment: if you want the geodesic distance yes you need to transform in cartesian coordinates if you want just the nearest, you could stay in lat/long degree like lat/lon are x y points, and so you dont care about distance, in this case its the euclidian distance

Comment: Also the distance calculated is in Kilo meter ? right @Frenchy

Comment: No if you keep lat lon in degree you'll have dist = euclian distance of this point with a unknown metric, if you want meter you have to use the cartesian before, or calcul the distance with geopy after the result -> you know the index of nearest point  of fleet for each row of actual

Comment: Yes I understood...The code is neat and clean..Thank you very much ....

Comment: Do you have any idea ??? @Frenchy.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55518674/how-to-cluster-latitude-and-longitude-data-in-python-or-remove-unwanted-data?noredirect=1#comment97743398_55518674