# How to predict the class by training only partial sequence as Input using LSTM's in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, generator, lstm

**Objective**

I would like to predict the class **if I give only partial input into the model**.
(Working with sequence data. Using Keras LSTM's)

**What I have done**

I have implemented my model based on the answers what I got from [here answered by @Kbrose](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/training-an-rnn-with-examples-of-different-lengths-in-keras)
In such a way, i should train my training data with variable length sequence which corresponds to particular class.

*Here, I would like to clarify some queries related to fit.generator, batch sizes, validation_steps and my Model results*

**Data**

```
X_train.shape = (243*100*4)  # Samples * Time steps * Features 
Y_train.shape = (243,)       # either 0 or 1 for each samples

X_validate.shape : (31, 100, 4) # Samples * Time steps * Features 
Y_validate.shape : (31,)        # either 0 or 1 for each samples

X_test.shape : (28, 100, 4) # Samples * Time steps * Features 
Y_test.shape : (28,)        # either 0 or 1 for each samples
```

**Objective:**

```
1. Train the model with random time length batches
2. Predict the class, if random time length batches provided as input to the model
```

**Code**

```
input_ = Input(shape=(None,4))
x = LSTM(16, return_sequences=True)(input_)   
x = LSTM(8, return_sequences=True)(x)  
output = TimeDistributed(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))(x)

# Model
model = Model(inputs=input_, outputs=output)

print(model.summary())

# Model Compile
model.compile(
  loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4),
  metrics=['accuracy']
)


def common_generator(X, Y):
  while True:
    sequence_length = random.randrange(60,100,5) 
    # I want my model to be trained with random time length b/w 50 to 100 with multiples of 5

    x_train = X[:, :sequence_length, :]

    y = to_categorical(Y) 
    y_train = np.repeat(y[:, np.newaxis], sequence_length, axis=1)

   # For my convenience i changed my Y_train shape from (243,) to (243, sequence_length, 2) 
   # Refer picture below for better understanding

    yield (x_train, y_train)

trainGen = common_generator(X_train,Y_train)
ValGen  = common_generator(X_validate, Y_validate)

H = model.fit_generator(trainGen, steps_per_epoch=30, validation_data=ValGen, validation_steps=3, epochs=100)
```

> **Question 1** : The model trained with 25 steps_per_epoch. What will be
>   the batch_sizes for one step ? It takes default value as 32 or >
>   number of samples//steps_per_epoch (In my case 243//25 = 9)
>
> **Question 2** : How to choose or select validation_steps ? What is the correct selection ? (In my case, there were 31 samples of validation_data)

[image]

**Training & Results**

After training for almost 100 epochs

```
Epoch 99/100
30/30 [==============================] - 6s 200ms/step - loss: 0.3055 - acc: 0.8789 - val_loss: 0.4075 - val_acc: 0.8259
Epoch 100/100
30/30 [==============================] - 6s 201ms/step - loss: 0.3051 - acc: 0.8791 - val_loss: 0.4051 - val_acc: 0.8260
```

[image]

> **Question 3** : What can i understand from the picture ?    From the graph, i believe it is Over fitting. How can I improve my model ?
>   Whether my model gets trained properly or not ?  Kindly comment

Comment: @Frenchy could you help me to sort this ?

Comment: i am in holidays until end of july.. but i'll see that in august if you havent answers

Comment: i dont see errors in your way to do.. simply you have not a "good" model... to improve your model (to reduce difference between predictive data and real data) you have to rethink your model...or cut your model by more little models..